# How to declare dynamic Internal table in ABAP in ALV

Tags: abap

http://sapscenarios.blogspot.in
I want to declare dynamic structure which contain a dynamic column in a internal table .
Structure is also dynamic .

Answer (score 3):

You can use cl_abap_structdescr=>create and cl_abap_tabledescr=>create to create a structure and table type dynamically. They are really easy to use and works like a charm the only limitation may be that it is only available from ECC6 (possibly ECC5).

```
data ls_component type abap_componentdescr.
data lt_component type abap_component_tab.
data lcl_struct type ref to cl_abap_structdescr.
data lr_data type ref to data.

ls_component-name = 'FIELD1'.
ls_component-type = cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_name( 'I' ).
append ls_component to lt_component.

lcl_struct = cl_abap_structdescr=>create( P_COMPONENTS = lt_component ).
create data lr_data type handle lcl_struct.
```

FYI there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15587774/how-to-generate-a-table-with-dynamic-amount-of-colums-and-a-fixed-set-of-rows/15610747#15610747) but the answer, although correct, is limited since it generates a subroutine pool and you can only do that 36 times. However [Denis Muzhzhukhin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2006334/denis-muzhzhukhin) gave the same answer I did here with a reference to the SAP help.